# Star Trek: Of Gods and Men - Where does it fit in the Star Trek timeline?

Tags: star-trek, movie

I am wondering where "[Star Trek : Of Gods and Men](http://www.startrekofgodsandmen.com/main/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=104&Itemid=168)" fits in with the star trek time line.

Comment: What episode? Please provide a link.

Answer (score 4):

"[Of Gods and Men"](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Of_Gods_and_Men) is not an official episode of Star Trek but is in fact a fan-made (3 part) film set in the Star Trek universe and starring various TOS Trek [characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Trek:_Of_Gods_and_Men#Returning_Star_Trek_cast_and_crew) as well as actors from other Trek series.

The show opens in 2305, some 12 years after the loss of Admiral Kirk in "Generations".

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  So I wold be able to fit it in somewhere in the series, like the star trek renegades (October 2014) would fit somewhere after Voyager.

Comment: Yes. If you wanted to strictly timeline it, it would fit in straight after generations, notwithstanding the fact that it contains time travel to the future